# Libre office pdf export is not correct

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, print-to-pdf, libreoffice-draw

I am trying to export my libre draw file to PDF. When I do so, some text is removed, and the positioning of one of the boxes is off.

I have tried viewing in multiple pdf viewers.

I am running on Linux Mint 18.2 and Libre Office version Version: 5.1.6.2.

All the draw file contains is a dark grey box. The box contains some large white font, and some small dark grey font with white highlighting. The small dark grey font and its higlight are not exported to the pdf.

In addition the dark grey box is perfectly fit to the document in libre draw, but in the pdf it is off on the right edge by 4 pixels.

Comment: Do you get the same result when printing to pdf as saving to pdf?

Comment: It would be easier to understand the issue if you could include screenshots of the LO document and the PDF.